# How to decrypt a recovered EFS file

Tags: windows, filesystems, data-recovery

I had a file that was encrypted using windows EFS on an NTFS filesystem. It was deleted accidentally and I had to recover it using a data recovery software. Unfortunately, recovered file isn't an encrypted one (although the file content is still encrypted).

Now I'm looking for a solution to access my encrypted data again (e.g. forcing Windows to see it as an encrypted file).

Any workaround would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The file isn't encrypted, but the content is? Can you explain that?

Comment: @schroeder As I mentioned before, this file is recovered from a formatted disk, I've also revocered some other unencrypted files without any problem, but about this file, windows doesn't consider it as an encrypted file. I also have the pfx file that was used for encryption (and of course its password), but I don't know how can I use it to decrypt my file.

Comment: how about creating a new encrypted file with the same pfx and same password and just changing the contents to those of the recovered file?

Comment: @EhsanKhodarahmi you never said the disk was formatted ....

Comment: @Purefan Because after editing the new file to add the encrypted contents Windows will then encrypt the contents a second time.  And when accessed Windows will decrypt the contents only once, providing access to the same encrypted file he has now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double-click the EFS certificate that you've backed up and import it into your current PC. It will prompt you to enter the original password. Once the password is validated, the certificate will be imported and your encrypted files will become readable.

Comment: Honestly, this is the only answer, to this question.  However, if NTFS no longer recongizes the fact the file is encrypted, there isn't very much you can do.

Comment: This only works if the file is recognized as encrypted by NTFS.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you're going to be able to use Windows to natively restore access to this file since, as you mention, the current file isn't seen as encrypted by Windows.  I'm guessing you restored the raw file and will need a program that can decrypt a blob of data rather than trying to decrypt it through the NTFS file system.

I found [this page](http://forensicswiki.org/wiki/Windows_Encrypted_File_System) that (while otherwise pretty terribly written) does offer the names of several third-party vendor solutions that *might* be able to help you recover the unencrypted contents.  I would start by looking into the ntfsdecrypt tool and the Elcomsoft tool.  They still might not operate on a low enough level to accomplish what you're hoping for, but seem like your best chance.